# How to compile scss to css in Sublime 4

Tags: sass, sublimetext4

I need some help with Sublime 4 please.

At the moment I use Prepros to compile my css.
I am trying to mimic the process of Prepros so i can us Sublime only.
I have:

- installed the SASS package,
- created build system: BuildIntoNewFolder
- selected Save All On Build

This is my setup:
I wrote my scss in hidden scss file here:
/assets/scss/_style-header.scss
and
/assets/scss/_style-footer.scss

The hidden scss are imported to:
/assets/scss/style.scss

The style.scss are the compiled to:
/assets/css/_style.css

This all happens by simply saving _style-header.scss
[image: Please see screenshot attached]

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your build system as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), not an image.